# Will TcpClient.NoDelay affect already written data?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

[TcpClient.NoDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay) docs state:

> Gets or sets a value that disables a delay when send or receive buffers are not full.

However, it's not clear whether this only applies to data written *after* it's set to `true`, or to data that has been written and is now waiting, as well. I.e. **When there's data in the buffer and `NoDelay` is *then* set to `true`, will the data in the buffer be sent immediately?**

Comment: The delay is implemented in the network card and normally waits 200ms so that small messages are combined into larger ones.  TCP max packet size is ~1500 bytes.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When there's data in the buffer and NoDelay is then set to true, will
> the data in the buffer be sent immediately?

**No.**

It gets evaluated on the next `Send` with valid data.

You can verify with `NoDelay = true` followed by `Send` with a few bytes.

Or set `NoDelay = true` without any call to `Send` after and you should see no change.

I verified using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), but use whatever packet inspection tool you prefer.

---

`TcpClient` is just a thin wrapper around `Socket`, so you can use [`Socket.NoDelay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay?view=net-5.0) the same way.

Socket options are set by this [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,6469) calling `setsockopt` which is [native code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-setsockopt):

```
errorCode = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.setsockopt(
    m_Handle,
    optionLevel,
    optionName,
    ref optionValue,
    sizeof(int));
```

The actual option being set in this case is [TCP_NODELAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-tcp-socket-options).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not very helpful with this, but consider this:

If there is still data in the buffer when you set `NoDelay` to `true` then it should affect the waiting bytes, because if you write more data it surly affects that. How should that work if not all bytes (written before and after setting `NoDelay` to `true`) were treated equally?

Can you be 100% sure about this? Not without asking the authors of `TcpClient` or inspecting its code.